# Adding a checkbox column to asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a couple questions when it pertains to adding a `CheckBox` column to `gridview` in `asp.net` and getting multiple values. First off I see everyone adding `OnCheckedChanged="chkview_CheckedChanged"` to their `aspx` page but when you click on the `CheckBox` to set its actions it does not open `OnCheckedChanged="chkview_CheckedChanged"`. It opens `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead. What I am trying to do is when they select a `CheckBox` it adds the corresponding rows info to the `TextBox`. Here is what I am currently using to set the values. How can I use a selected `CheckBox`  instead?

```
protected void dropGridView_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = dropdeadGridView.SelectedRow;
    IDTextBox.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
    loadnumTextBox.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Once done with that how can you make it to where it will get every row that is checked instead of just one which is what is my current problem. I am looking for a way to select multiple rows and have a select button. I have done a lot of looking and can find nothing on it so I am trying to accomplish this with `CheckBoxes` instead. Any ideas how I can add this and get the multiple rows that can be selected. Thank you in advance.

Here is my edit* Posting asp code for `CheckBox` column:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you have to set autopostback attribute to true :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="SelectCheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
              OnCheckedChanged="SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged"/>
```

In your case, `SelectedIndexChanged` is sent by the gridview. For the checkbox event you have to use `OnCheckedChanged` event :

```
protected void SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox ;

    if(chk.Checked)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;
        IDTextBox.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        loadnumTextBox.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
    }
}
```

If you want to loop through all selected checkboxes :

```
var rows = dropdeadGridView.Rows;
int count = dropdeadGridView.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)rows[i].FindControl("chkBox")).Checked;
    if(isChecked)
    {
        //Do what you want
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not populate textbox

Comment: I also put breakpoints on the OnCheckedChanged event and when checked it does not break.

Comment: I was going to ask =)

Comment: Still no record displayed could it be the selectedindexchanged messing it up?

Comment: Do you enter SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged method?

Comment: It does not reach my selectedindexchanged either

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49250/discussion-between-plue-and-kpt-khaos)

Comment: On your loop reccomendation...It can be done in one line. Much easier to use for each. foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows) instead of var rows = dropdeadGridView.Rows;
int count = dropdeadGridView.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)

Answer (score 0):

HTML Gridview example

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Class="table table-striped table-bordered" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="40px" Width="80%" EmptyDataText="No Stock in The Shop"> <Columns> <asp:TemplateField> <HeaderTemplate> <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAllSelect" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" /> </HeaderTemplate> <ItemTemplate> <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" onclick="Check_Click(this);EnableBTN(this);" runat="server" /> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> <asp:BoundField DataField="SHOP_CODE" HeaderText="SHOP CODE" /> <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_CODE" HeaderText="ITEM CODE" /> <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_NAME" HeaderText="ITEM NAME" /> <asp:BoundField DataField="COLOR_CODE" HeaderText="COLOR CODE" /> <asp:BoundField DataField="COLOR_NAME" HeaderText="COLOR NAME" /> <asp:BoundField DataField="STOCK_NO" HeaderText="STOCK NUMBER" /> <asp:BoundField DataField="STOCK_IN_HAND" HeaderText="STOCK IN HAND" /> <asp:BoundField DataField="LOCATION_CD" HeaderText="LOCATION" />    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NO OF QUANTITY"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" Placeholder="Enter The Correct Qty" ID="ADJqty" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Text=""></asp:TextBox> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>          </Columns> </asp:GridView>`

Use this function check all the gridview check box

```
        function checkAll(objRef) {
            var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
                //Get the Cell To find out ColumnIndex
                var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
                if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
                    if (objRef.checked) {
                        //If the header checkbox is checked
                        //check all checkboxes
                        //and highlight all rows
                        row.style.backgroundColor = "#e3f1ff";
                        inputList[i].checked = true;
                        $('#DummyBTNAUTHLeave').prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#DummyBTNRJTLeave').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                    else {
                        //If the header checkbox is checked
                        //uncheck all checkboxes
                        //and change rowcolor back to original
                        if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                            //Alternating Row Color
                            row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.05)";
                        }
                        else {
                            row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                        }
                        inputList[i].checked = false;
                        $('#DummyBTNAUTHLeave').prop('disabled', true);
                        $('#DummyBTNRJTLeave').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

check the specifyed checkbox in gridview

```
        function Check_Click(objRef) {
            //Get the Row based on checkbox
            var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;
            if (objRef.checked) {
                //If checked change color to Aqua
                row.style.backgroundColor = "#e3f1ff";
            }
            else {
                //If not checked change back to original color
                if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                    //Alternating Row Color
                    row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.05)";
                }
                else {
                    row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                }
            }
            //Get the reference of GridView
            var GridView = row.parentNode;
            //Get all input elements in Gridview
            var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
                //The First element is the Header Checkbox
                var headerCheckBox = inputList[0];
                //Based on all or none checkboxes
                //are checked check/uncheck Header Checkbox
                var checked = true;
                if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i] != headerCheckBox) {
                    if (!inputList[i].checked) {
                        checked = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            headerCheckBox.checked = checked;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).